# How do I do conditional logic between rows of a bigquery table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a query that goes through a table row by row comparing the current row with the next. Then based on a condition being true will perform a calculation which is then output in a column on the same table and a null value if false.

[image: Current table]

Consider the example above:

- Row 8703 will be referred to as Row 1
- Row 8704 will be referred to as Row 2

I would like to, if possible, compare Row 1 bookedEnd with Row 2 bookedStart. If they are of equal value (which in this case they are) I would like to subtract Row 2 actualStartdate from Row 1 actualEnddate and output the value in minutes in a separate column named 'difference' on Row 2.
If they are not of equal value (which is true for all other columns in the example above) I would like to output a null value.

For the above table the extra column named difference would have the row values of:

- 8701 - Null
- 8702 - Null
- 8703 - Null
- 8704 - 12
- 8705 - Null

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.  Also, a clear explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are writing to "Row 2", I use the `LAG()` function so you are comparing on the row you are writing.

```
with data as (select * from `project.dataset.table`),
lagged as (
  select 
    *,
    lag(bookedEnd,1) over(partition by roomID order by Row asc) as prev_bookedEnd,
    lag(actualEnddate,1) over(partition by roomID order by Row asc) as prev_actualEnddate
  from data
)
select 
  * except (prev_bookedEnd,prev_actualEnddate),
  case when prev_bookedEnd = bookedStart then timestamp_diff(prev_actualEndDate,actualStartdate, minute) else null end as difference
from lagged
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do in this scenario is use the lead function
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lead
it would look similar to

```
SELECT bookedEnd
, CASE WHEN bookedEnd = LEAD(bookedStart) OVER (PARTITION BY roomid ORDER BY Row) then XXXX END as actualStartdate
, CASE WHEN bookedEnd = LEAD(bookedStart) OVER (PARTITION BY roomid ORDER BY Row) then XXXX END as difference
```

Comment: as an additional note there is also LAG which would be previous records. In both LEAD AND LAG you can control the offset, but default is 1. Also you can specify a default.  You will typically need this in the scenario of the last record in a set because there will be no subsequent row to look at in the case of LEAD and the first record in the case of LAG.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *, 
  IF( LAG(bookedEnd) OVER (PARTITION BY roomId ORDER BY bookedStart) = bookedStart, 
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF( actualStartdate, 
                      LAG(actualEnddate) OVER (PARTITION BY roomId ORDER BY bookedStart), 
                      MINUTE
                    ), 
      NULL
    ) AS difference
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```